# How do this sql query in rails 2.3?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I need this sql query in a function in my controller in ***ruby on rails 2.3***.

```
SELECT name, created_at AS "date" FROM table1 WHERE created_at = '2015-07-15' ORDER by created_at;
```

This is because I have two more queries before this one, and they have a field named 'date', and I need to concatenate every one and sort them by the field named 'date', and just this last one table don't have a field named 'date'.

Comment: Did you already tried something in ruby?

Comment: Ok, I found this solution that helps me, for another person maybe need it..  `table1.find_by_sql["SELECT name, created_at AS 'date' FROM table1 WHERE created_at = '2015-07-15' ORDER by created_at"]` Thanks anyways! :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found this solution that helps me, for another person maybe need it..

`table1.find_by_sql["SELECT name, created_at AS 'date' FROM table1 WHERE created_at = '2015-07-15' ORDER by created_at"]`

Then I can sort all my query results (including the previous tables) by the field 'date'..